# Filter a list based on a property that is inside another list it contains

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have an order object with its partial class containing changes history:

```
public class SomeOrder
{
    public string SomeOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeOrderChangesHistory> ChangesHistory { get; set; }
}

public partial class SomeOrderChangesHistory
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I'll be getting a list of `SomeOrder` and I want to filter out the orders if they are updated by `api user`.

The orders updated by `api user` will have one or more `SomeOrderChangesHistory` object in the `ChangesHistory` list with `api user` value in the `UserName` property (in `SomeOrderChangesHistory` object).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter out"? Are you using EF/EF Core?

Comment: @NetMage EF doesn't come into play for this. I just receive a JSON response then I parse it into C# objects, and I need to remove the orders that are updated by `api user` because I only need orders that are updated by person. The answer posted below solves my problem but I don't know why it's down voted.

Comment: (It wasn't me.) Probably because LINQ should be used to create new collections with the criteria desired, and modifying the original list in a method named `Filter` seems a bad idea, especially since it returns a `List` that is the same one passed in (good for Fluent programming, bad if you expect LINQ behavior). It would be better named `Remove`... Also there is a lot of unneccessary null-checking (`?.`) going on.

Comment: Using LINQ, you could expect to do something like `var peopleOrders = orders.Where(o => !o.ChangeHistory.Any(ch => ch.UserName == "api user")).ToList()`.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you, your answer looks very concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @NetMage's excellent comment:

```
var ordersNotUpdatedByAPIUser = orders
                                .Where(o => !o.ChangeHistory.Any(ch => ch.UserName == "api user"))
                                .ToList()
```

It will filter **out** all the orders updated by `api user` which is exactly what I want.